# How to add blank row above specific text?

Tags: excel, vba

How to add a blank row on a file above the word "Costumer"?

Found the below one but can't make it work on the specific worksheet on the workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").("1").EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("1:7").EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("b:b,d:d,f:f,h:j,m:n,p:p,v:x,z:z,ab:ab,ad:ad,af:al").EntireColumn.Delete

'ADDS BLANK ROW ABOVE "Customer account" CELLS
Dim d As Integer
d = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Like "0" Then
      Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot make it work'? What error are you getting?

Comment: No error shows but doesn't work. Do i need to referer to the worksheet maybe? Thank you

Comment: It works for me. Did you change the search range (A:A) to the one you wanted?

Comment: The specifici text "Customer account" is on column A. I am adding the code to other code that will run together. Do i need to refer to the worksheet? Thanks

Comment: Have added the complete code to run with the add blank row

Comment: Working now, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for "0" not for the word "Customer"

```
    Sub LoopIt()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, x

    Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")

    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = LstRw To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(x, 1) Like "*Customer*" Then
                .Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If

        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```